# Unable to Query a View from a Linked SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, select, view, linked-server

In SQL Server Management Studio, I have linked a SQL Server, `sql02` to my local server as such:

```
sp_addlinkedserver 'sql02'
GO
```

I can query tables from this server:

```
SELECT * FROM SQL02.SomeDatabase.dbo.SomeTable
```

However, when I try to query a view, as in

```
SELECT * FROM SQL02.SomeDatabase.dbo.SomeView
```

I get the following error message:

```
Msg 7314, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "SQL02" does not contain the 
table ""SomeDatabase"."dbo"."SomeView"". The table either does not exist or the
current user does not have permissions on that table.
```

Agreed that `SomeView` does not exist as a table. What am I doing wrong?

Potentially relevant facts:

- Local version of SQL Server is 10.50.1617
- Version of linked server is 8.0.2282
- I can SELECT from all the underlying tables in the view

Comment: Do you have permission to SELECT from the view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a permission issue, have you checked the permissions on the view? There's nothing wrong with your query.

Also, have you checked what table does that view query on? Check the table permissions as well.

As a tip: Try to run the view on a specific user and if that's successful try to link the server using that specific user.

Comment: Yep. That's all it was. I'd checked everything except my permission to execute this view!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue hit me tonight because it's the first time I've had to integrate view data from a linked server into an IIS publication.

While I knew that I needed to create a SQL login on the linked server side and map the resources I didn't check 'db_datareader'. Checking that fixed the issue.