# unable to login using linked server configuration, giving error about don't have permission in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, linked-server

i have a scenario where i have to use two tables of two different databases on the same server. 
i have configured  my linkserver using this-

```
USE master;  
   EXEC sp_addlinkedserver     
   @server=N'commbridgenew',   
   @srvproduct=N'',  
   @provider=N'SQLNCLI',   
   @datasrc=N'vicky-PC\SQLSERVER2012';
```

when i run my query on local it works fine -

```
select * from ecomm.dbo.Articles att
INNER JOIN commbridgenew.bloggerDB.dbo.bloggers b
ON att.Bid=B.Bid
```

but it gives error when i run this query on my server ..

```
Msg 7314, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "commbridgenew" does not contain the table ""bloggerDB"."dbo"."bloggers"". The table either does not exist or the current user does not have permissions on that table.
```

Some thing like it .

i am unable to get the point ..

Any help .. please

Comment: Check below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087843/unable-to-query-a-view-from-a-linked-sql-server

Comment: yeah , i get your point and tried ...
Under Linked Server on expanding my linked server name , i am geting only my two databases , in which one is not showing any table . i am not getting where to set permissions for this .  i have only execute a exec linked server script as shown above .. can you explain where to set permissions ???

Answer (score 0):

this error means that the user that is used in a linked server doesn't have access to this table on this DB: bloggerDB.dbo.bloggers
to fix the permissions on the linked server - ask a DBA to add at least read permissions to that DB, for example:

```
use bloggerDB --on  a linked server with admin permissions!
go
CREATE USER [linkedServerUser] FOR LOGIN [LinkedServerLogin] --replace the names as should
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datareader', N'linkedServerUser'
```

Comment: by the way, if the databases are on the same server - you DON'T need a linked server for that! just use <dbname>.<dbo>.<tablename>

Comment: but my credentials are different for both database then how i can use in this way > is it possible bro

Comment: i have configured  linked server as i told above . is it okay .... where i will define any USER or DATABASE ... it seems to me uncomplete ?

Answer (score 0):

My Linked server configuration not working properly , some configuration issues on Live , BUt i find a solution -
I have create a common user who can access both of my DB and given them enough permissions. That solved my issues.

Comment: If you truly have "two tables of two different databases on the same server." then you should not be using linked servers. Instead just use three part naming convention: `database.schema.table`